# CRUD method for a model that belongs_to many models Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, model-associations

I'm new to Rails and I might be missing something very basic here:

User can create contact for both branches and division of a company

**Branch.rb**

```
class Branch < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :contacts
end
```

**Division.rb**

```
class Division < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :company
    has_many :contacts
end
```

**Contact.rb**

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :branch
    belongs_to :division
end
```

Now a user can create a contact from the branch page where there is no division_id and can create a contact from the Division page.

I have defined my routes.rb like this:

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :companies, :shallow => true do
    get 'company_page'
    resources :branches, :shallow => true do
        get 'branch_page'
        resources :contacts
    end 
    resources :divisions, :shallow => true do
        get 'division_page'
        resources :contacts
    end 
end
```

As a result, if I create a contact from either Branch or Division, it goes to contacts#create method.

In my contacts_controller.rb, I have:

```
def create
    @newContact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    id = @division = @branch = nil
    isBranch = false
    if params[:branch_id] != nil
        isBranch = true
        id = params[:branch_id]
    else
        isBranch = false
        id = params[:division_id]
    end 
    if isBranch
      branch = Branch.find(id) 
      @newContact.branch = branch
      @branch = branch
    else
      division = Division.find(id) 
      @newContact.division = division
      @division = division
    end  

    respond_to do |format|
        if @newContact.save
          format.js
          format.html { render :nothing => true, :notice => 'Contact created successfully!' }
          format.json { render json: @newContact, status: :created, location: @newContact }
        else
          format.html { render action: "new" }
          format.json { render json: @newContact, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end     
end
```

But I have facing `ActiveRecord Error` during `@newContact.save`.

I'm sure I am doing something fundamentally very wrong here and Rails handles such things in another elegant way which I don't know of.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 265ms (ActiveRecord: 66.8ms)`

Comment: i'm guessing the error is because `Contact` has two belongs to associations but you're only giving it one.  What's the error in log/development.log ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct on that. I want to know how to handle that. The issue is `@newContact.save is false` hence it is going to the else block of the `respond_to do |format| block`.

Comment: you can do `belongs_to :branch, optional: true; belongs_to :division, optional: true`

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of `optional` in Rails model. Is my controller method okay for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Anthony noted, you'll need to make your `belongs_to` associations optional:

```
# app/models/contact.rb

class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :branch, optional: true
  belongs_to :division, optional: true
end
```

But another problem is that `params[:division_id]` and `params[:branch_id]` are always nil. Both of those keys exist inside the `[:contact]` key. So the error you are getting should be `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Division with 'id'=`

All that conditional logic is unnecessary. You can just make a new contact with whatever params are given. Also, you should be using Ruby convention for variable naming, which is snake_case instead of camelCase.

Finally, I assume you'll want to redirect HTML requests to either the branch or the division show page, depending on which was associated. So I've added logic to do that.

Here's a quick refactoring of the controller `#create` action:

```
  def create
    @new_contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    if @new_contact.save
      branch = @new_contact.branch
      division = @new_contact.division
      redirect_path = branch ? branch_path(branch) : division_path(division)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html { redirect_to redirect_path, :notice => 'Contact created successfully!' }
        format.json { render json: @new_contact, status: :created, location: @new_contact }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @new_contact, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This proves that it works:

```
# spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ContactsController, type: :controller do
  let(:company) { Company.create!(name: 'Company Name') }
  let(:division) { Division.create!(name: 'Division Name', company: company) }
  let(:branch) { Branch.create!(name: 'Branch Name', company: company) }

  describe '#create' do
    context 'when created with a division id' do
      let(:attributes) { {'division_id' => division.id, 'name' => 'Contact Name'} }

      it 'creates a contact record and associates it with the division' do
        expect(Contact.count).to eq(0)
        post :create, params: {contact: attributes}

        expect(Contact.count).to eq(1)
        contact = Contact.first
        expect(contact.division).to eq(division)
      end
    end

    context 'when created with a branch id' do
      let(:attributes) { {'branch_id' => branch.id, 'name' => 'Contact Name'} }

      it 'creates a contact record and associates it with the branch' do
        expect(Contact.count).to eq(0)
        post :create, params: {contact: attributes}

        expect(Contact.count).to eq(1)
        contact = Contact.first
        expect(contact.branch).to eq(branch)
      end
    end
  end
end
```